# silverllight metadata validation c#

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have a webservice that gets data from  SQLServer using linq, how do i use metadata annotations to achieve this?

The class contains 2 strings UserName and Password.
Im using Silverlight 4 and c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at [WCF RIA services](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/) where you can reuse metadata for validation.